# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

**UPDATE:** The election has now [been scheduled](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/q/126/26). Thanks to all who expressed interest in nominating.

---

It is time for us to consider holding a new election for moderators for the Cardano SE.

The [last election](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election/1) we held was back in Q2 2021, where we elected three moderators.
One of those has been recently removed due to inactivity.

It is proposed to hold a new election to get ourselves back up to a more regularly-available and active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I am posting here to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves.

Please leave an answer if you would like to run for a moderator position.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the election has been scheduled and the community interest check is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

I’d love to help moderate. I don’t have much moderation experience, on stack exchange, but I’m up for the challenge.

Comment: I suggest you spend time building your reputation, gaining access to the edit review queues, etc.  Moderation is pretty light at this stage from my point of view, but that may be due to me being in UTC+10 (Australia).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest anyone interested in Moderation/site direction, etc. start chatting about it in our chat room (Loveplace)